# Windows instrumentation profiling of native app tool

Tags: windows, visual-studio, profiling, instrumentation

Looking for something ideally as good as Visual Studio 2017 Diagnostic Tools CPU usage (while debugging very invaluable as one can profile the app between 2 breakpoints -> and you get profiling results in that interval) **but for instrumentation**. So I'm interested in function timings, no CPU usage in order to detect IO or other types of waitings in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concurrency Visualizer, an extension for Visual Studio fits the bill. It can report concurrency delays, one can see synchronisation points with the interthread dependencies, even has IO reported. A very goot tool, equivalent with Xperf for VS. Does not use instrumentation though, but because it exposes this synchronisation points it is more effective than instrumentation in concurrent apps.